# pdo to download database records into excel file

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

So I had this working before while i used mysql functions but now how to get this to work in pdo?

Would really appreciate if someone could help out as pdo is new to me.

**Code:**

```
<?php
require_once('_db.php');
$y =$_REQUEST['y'];
$m =$_REQUEST['m'];
$date = "$y-$m";
$todays = date("d-m-Y");
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Reservations-'.$date.'.csv');
$select_table=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '$date' ORDER BY id DESC");
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_table);
if ($rows){
    getcsv(array_keys($rows));
}
while($rows){
    getcsv($rows);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_table);
}
function getcsv($no_of_field_names){
    $separate = '';
    foreach ($no_of_field_names as $field_name){
        if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field_name)){
            $field_name = '' . str_replace('', $field_name) . '';
        }
        echo $separate . $field_name;
        $separate = ',';
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please edit your post to show the progress you've made so far, not the code you don't want to use any more.

Comment: i have done this much is this right?

$select_table = "SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '$date' ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt = $db->prepare($select_table);
$stmt->execute();

Comment: where is the issue? what is the problem?

Comment: ok i fixed if i replaced 

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); with $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); and its working